# Position widget anywhere without pushing other widgets

Tags: android, ios, flutter

I've followed a Flutter youtube tutorial and ended up with a layout like this:

[image: https://i.imgur.com/BGLQPma.png]

How can I move CircleAvatar widget far right and bring other widgets up? So it looks like this (I photoshoped this):

[image]

This is what some of my code looks like:

```
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      backgroundColor: Colors.grey[900],
      appBar: AppBar(
        title: Text("User information"),
        centerTitle: true,
        backgroundColor: Colors.grey[850],
        elevation: 0.0,
      ),
      floatingActionButton: FloatingActionButton(
        onPressed: () {
          setState( () { 
            userLevel++;
          });
        },
        backgroundColor: Colors.red[400],
        child: Icon(Icons.add),
      ),
      body: Padding(
        padding: EdgeInsets.fromLTRB(30.0, 35.0, 30.0, 0.0),
        child: Column(
          crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,
          children: <Widget>[
            Center(
              child: CircleAvatar(
                backgroundImage: AssetImage("assets/vayneAvatar.jpg"),
                radius: 40.0,
              ),
            ),
            Divider(height: 60.0, color: Colors.grey[700]),
            Text(
              "USERNAME",
              style: TextStyle(
                color: Colors.grey,
                letterSpacing: 2.0,
              ),
            ),
            SizedBox(height: 8.0),
            Text(
              "user1",
              style: TextStyle(
                color: Colors.red[400],
                fontWeight: FontWeight.bold,
                fontSize: 22.0,
                letterSpacing: 2.0,
              ),
            ),
```

Thanks!

Comment: Use stack widget

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to use [Stack widget](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/widgets/Stack-class.html) which takes list of children, where you can easily position your widgets by [Positioned widget](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/widgets/Positioned-class.html).